# which UITextView is initiating textViewDidChange in Swift?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I have a number of UITextViews in my ViewController.  I am using the textViewDidChange method to handle certain user interaction:

```
func textViewDidChange(textView: UITextView) { // do something
    }
```

My question is, how do I determine which textview is initiating this function, i.e. which textview is the sender?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also try this simple technique.

```
func textViewDidChange(textView: UITextView) {

  //textView(Sender)
   if(textView == yourtextview)
   {
     //do something
   } 

}
```

Answer (score 2):

you can identify the text views by reference

```
var textview1 : UITextView!
var textview2 : UITextView!

func textViewDidChange(textView: UITextView) { // do something
    switch (textView) {
    case textview1: // do something with textview1
    case textview2: // do something with textview2
    default: break
    }
}
```

or assign tags and identify the views by tag. There are several ways.